# Podfile for both ios8 and ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

What do I have to write on Podfile to launch my application **on both ios8, ios9 devices**?

In the Podfile, if I write

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

It will crash when I launch the application on ios8 device:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CFE-45CC-429B-88E7-52E123/MYAPP.app/MYAPP
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CAFE-45CC-429B-88E7-52212593/MYAPP.app/MYAPP
```

Note: I am using XCode7.1 Beta, Objective-C, CocoaPod  0.38.0

Comment: why not `platform :ios, '8.0'`

Comment: I think platform: ios, '8.0', the pod framework will be updated to be compatible with ios 8.0, not ios 9.0. So that's why I leave it as '9.0'

Comment: it supposed to be the lowest version you support, in our projects we do support `7.0` , it works fine with ios 9 devices as well. However there are other issues with pods introduced with xcode 7- ios 9  that we had to resolve `platform :ios, '7.0'` remains the same in our podfiles....

Comment: what issues is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The platform line in your Podfile should be set to the lowest supported version. In otherwords use this:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'
```